# get route from url

Tags: controller, routes, symfony

In **Symfony2**, do you know how to find a route from a url in controller?
I have this example:

```
$params = $router->match('/blog/my-blog-post');
// array('slug' => 'my-blog-post', '_controller' => 'AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show')

$uri = $router->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
// /blog/my-blog-post
```

I would like find `blog_show` when i have `/blog/my-blog-post`

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know what you have in that `$router`, but with the router service, I get this here:

```
$this->get('router')->match('/')

array
  '_controller' => string 'Namespace\Foo\MyController::indexAction'
  '_route' => string 'home'
```

If you want the route name of the current page by the way you can just read it from the request object: `$request->attributes->get('_route')`.

Comment: $router: it's symfony doc example. I their example they don't show '_route'. I will use it, thank you ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that the match() method uses the HTTP METHOD of the current request in order to match the request. So if you are doing a PUT request for example, it will try to match the URL you have given with a PUT method, resulting in a MethodNotAllowedException exception (for example, getting the referer).

See more in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506062/100675

Answer (score 1):

you can get the same error if using absolute paths this is what I did when needed to match the referrer

```
$ref = str_replace("app_dev.php/", "", parse_url($request->headers->get('referer'),PHP_URL_PATH ));
$route = $this->container->get('router')->match($ref)['_route'];
```

Comment: Nice one but it does not work if you're using other environments than "dev" and "prod", which may be the case for some developers.