# Symfony2 Get route name from URL

Tags: symfony

ok you can get current route name with `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` but it's not possible to get from an url ?

Something like `app.request.attributes.get('/about')` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `Router` class/service for this:

```php
public function indexAction()
{
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $route = $router->match('/foo')['_route'];
}
```

More information in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls)

Comment: I used this but it's not valid. The Route service in Symfony has state of current request. For get the real route you should set context created from request with HTTP method that can be POST, PATCH or PUT or any other.

Answer (score 10):

I recently discovered that the match() method uses the HTTP METHOD of the current request in order to match the request. So if you are doing a PUT request for example, it will try to match the URL you have given with a PUT method, resulting in a MethodNotAllowedException exception (for example, getting the referer).

To avoid this I'm using this workaround:

```
// set context with GET method of the previous ajax call
$context = $this->get('router')->getContext();
$currentMethod = $context->getMethod();
$context->setMethod('GET');

// match route
$routeParams = $this->get('router')->match($routePath);

// set back original http method
$context->setMethod($currentMethod);
```

However it may not be true that it's always a GET request. It could be a POST request in your case.

I've sent this problem to the Symfony community. Let's see what they propose.

Comment: You can force `HEAD` method instead `GET`. If you check `appDevUrlMatcher.php` or `appProdUrlMatcher.php` in your cache files, you will see `HEAD` method is always allowed for all routes. With this you will no longer need to estimate which method use to match referer.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the MethodNotAllowed even with matching methods when using absolute paths 
I worked around it like this

```
$ref = str_replace("app_dev.php/", "", parse_url($request->headers->get('referer'),PHP_URL_PATH ));
$route = $this->container->get('router')->match($ref)['_route'];
```