# Matching a URL to a route in Symfony

Tags: symfony, url-routing

We have files behind authentication, and I want to do different things for post-authentication redirect if the user entered the application using a URL of a file versus a URL of an HTML resource.

I have a URL: `https://subdomain.domain.com/resource/45/identifiers/567/here/11abdf51e3d7-some%20file%20name.png/download`.  I want to get the route name for this URL.

`app/console router:debug` outputs this: `_route_name      GET      ANY    subdomain.domain.{tld}   /resource/{id2}/identifiers/{id2}/here/{id3}/download`.

Symfony has a Routing component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), and I'm trying to call `match()` on an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router` as provided by Symfony IOC.  I have tried with with the domain and without the domain, but they both create a `MethodNotAllowed` exception because the route cannot be found.  How can I match this URL to a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506062/3905211), Symfony uses *current* request's HTTP method while matching. I guess your controller serves POST request, while your download links are GET.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This may be what I end up doing, but it won't work for different request types.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late but as I was facing the same problem, what I come to is something like

```
$request = Request::create($targetPath, Request::METHOD_GET, [], [], [], $_SERVER);

try {
    $matches = $router->matchRequest($request);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // throw a 400
}
```

The key part is to use `$_SERVER` superglobal array in order to have all things setted straight away.

Answer (score 0):

The route name is available in the `_route_name` attribute of the `Request` object: `$request->attributes->get('_route_name')`.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The current request is not the one for which I want the route.  I want to get the route for an arbitrary URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ton get the route name:

```
public/protected/private function getRefererRoute(Request $request = null)
{
    if ($request == null)
        $request = $this->getRequest();

    //look for the referer route
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    $path = substr($referer, strpos($referer, $request->getBaseUrl()));
    $path = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $lastPath);

    $matcher = $this->get('router')->getMatcher();
    $parameters = $matcher->match($path);
    $route = $parameters['_route'];

    return $route;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to explain what I was doing. So basicly you are getting the page url (`$referer`) then taking out your website's base url with `str_replace` and then trying to match the remaining part of the path with a know route pattern using route matcher.

**EDIT2:**
Obviously you need to have this inside you controller if you want to be able to use `$this->get(...)`